# for loop with set: key

Tags: python, for-loop, set

I get a Keyerror when doing a for loop on a set of int values.

Here is the code:

```
# groupes : dict[str:set[int]]
groupes = {'cinephiles':{802,125,147,153}, \
'travaux manuels':{125,802,153}, \
'cuisine':{153,147,802}, \
'sport':{153,538,802}}

# This first function helps me for the second one

def proximite_groupes(group, hobby_1, hobby_2):
    """ 
       dict[str:set[int]] * str * str -> float
    """

    # intersection_set : set[int]
    intersection_set = set()
    # union_set : set[int]
    union_set = set()

    # cle : int
    for cle in group[hobby_1]:
        if cle in group[hobby_2]:
            intersection_set.add(cle)


    for cle in group[hobby_1]:
        if cle not in union_set:
            union_set.add(cle)

    for cle in group[hobby_2]:
        if cle not in union_set:
            union_set.add(cle)


    return len(intersection_set) / len(union_set)


def fusion_groupes(group):
    """ 
       dict[str:set[int]] -> dict[str:set[int]]
    """

    # similarite_max : int
    similarite_max = 0.0
    # str_1 : str
    # str_2 : str
    # str_1_final : str
    str_1_final = ''
    str_2_final = ''
    # str_1_final : str
    # str_final : str
    str_final = ' '
    # final_dict : dict[str:set[int]]
    final_dict = group
    # intersection_set : set[int]
    intersection_set = set()

    for str_1 in group:
        for str_2 in group:
            if str_1 != str_2:
                if proximite_groupes(group, str_1, str_2) > similarite_max:
                    similarite_max = proximite_groupes(group, str_1, str_2)
                    str_final = str_1 + '_' + str_2
                    str_1_final = str_1
                    str_2_final = str_2

    del final_dict[str_1_final]
    del final_dict[str_2_final]

    # Creation ensemble union
    for cle in group[str_1_final]:
        if cle in group[str_2_final]:
            intersection_set.add(cle)

    final_dict[str_final] = intersection_set

    return final_dict
```

The purpose of the function is a little bit hard to difficult, but my problem here is:

```
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 261, in fusion_groupes (note that the line would not be the same for you because my program has more lines)
KeyError: 'cuisine'
```

(but one time it's 'cuisine', the other time its 'cinephiles', or 'sport', ...

Comment: It looks like you cut out the actual code line while editing the traceback.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: The traceback usually contains code, yours does not. It has some remarks instead. The missing code makes is far less helpful.

Comment: When you add an item to a set you don't need to check whether they are incident, sets aren’t multisets.

Comment: Also, sets support [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) and [union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) operations, no need to roll your own. Your whole first function could be written as `def proximite_groupes(group, hobby_1, hobby_2): return len(groupes[hobby1] & groupes[hobby2]) / len(groupes[hobby1] | groupes[hobby2])` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents on these lines being the culprit.
`final_dict = group
 del final_dict[str_1_final]
 del final_dict[str_2_final]` .
This has to do with the fact that python does not deep copy your dictionary named group into final_dict. Instead final_dict is just referencing group. So when you delete the key from final_dict, it gets deleted from group as well. And the code below it:
`for cle in group[str_1_final]:` .
Fails.
Here's the sample of what happened: https://trinket.io/python/64f20460d9

Comment: As a solution, use this: final_dict = dict(group) OR final_dict = group.copy(), And then continue with your code